# Passing binary data from Qt/C++ DLL into Delphi host application

Tags: c++, delphi, qt, dll, qimage

In a Program I want to uses QImage.bits() in Delphi. So, in Qt I was created a dll. the dll Source Code Listed in below:

test.h:

```
  #ifndef TEST_H
    #define TEST_H

    #include "test_global.h"


    extern "C"{
    TESTSHARED_EXPORT uchar* testFunc();
    }


    #endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp:

```
 #include "test.h"
#include <QtGui>

QImage image;

uchar* testFunc(){
    image.load("c:\\1.png","PNG");
    return (uchar*)image.constBits();
}
```

and in the Delphi Side I use this code for using Qt dll:

```
    function testFunc(): PByteArray; external 'test.dll';
// ...

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bStream: TBytesStream;
  P: PByteArray;
  Size: Cardinal;
begin
  P := testFunc;
  Size := Length(PAnsiChar(P)); // AnsiChar = 1 Byte
  bStream := TBytesStream.Create();
  try
    bStream.Write(P[0], Size); // Works Fine (^_^)
    bStream.Position := 0;
    bStream.SaveToFile('c:\scr.txt');
  finally
    bStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

when I call dll function no any data returned! 
can you help me?

**Update 1:**
In real situation my Qt function is very complex and I can't write it in Delphi for many reasons. In fact orginal function taked a screenShot from a device and work on It in Main Memory. and as a result I want send this image bytes to Delphi for Show It on a TImage whit no save It on Hard Disk and similar memories. and in this topic I just created a simple similar function for simple debugging and testability. Is It Possible to help me by Writing a True Simple code for this problem? thanx a lot for you. (-_-)

Comment: No need for Qt here. You can read PNG files from Delphi.

Comment: why that mess with TByteStream ? Why not use TFileStream directly ?

Comment: Answer to "Arioch The" question: but in the real situation there isn't exists any png image file and image returned from a device. so, for decrease response time I can't use any file and my application must be used main memory for loading image data and show it. my Qt function is very very complex and It isn't possible for me to convert It to delphi source code.

Comment: Answer For "David Heffernan": I know that. but this source code is a simple simulation of my real problem.

Comment: OK then you just need to get the calling convention right and map `uchar*` to `PByte`. That's it.

Comment: @Shuhin - SO uses "twitter" convention when answering. Use "@" before name. That would notify your correspondent he has new unread reply.

Comment: Frankly, if response time that important why not make the monolithic program, all-Delphi or all-Qt ?

Comment: @David - not enough: he also has to pass the length of data blob, not only pointer to its head :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. (^_^)

For solving It:

In Qt Side:

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include "test_global.h"


extern "C"{
TESTSHARED_EXPORT char* testFunc(int &a);
}


#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <QtGui>

QImage image;
QByteArray ba;


char* testFunc(int &a){
    image.load("c:\\2.png","PNG");
    QBuffer buffer(&ba);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    image.save(&buffer,"PNG");
    a = ba.size();
    return ba.data();
}
```

In Delphi Side:

```
function testFunc(var aByteCount: DWORD): PByte;cdecl external 'test.dll';

// ...
var
  bStream: TBytesStream;
  Size: DWORD;
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: PByte;
  s: TStringList;
begin
  Caption := '0';
  P := testFunc(Size);
  bStream := TBytesStream.Create();
  try
    bStream.Write(P[0], Size);
    bStream.Position := 0;
    bStream.SaveToFile('c:\my.png');
  finally
    Caption := IntToStr(Size);
  end;
end;
```

Thanx again for "Arioch The" and ""David Heffernan"". (^_^)

Comment: @David his answer has value as a working code.
Though i agree that by SO spirit such code sample would better be appended as Update 2 in original question, rather than independent answer.

Comment: @Arioch'The Clearly Shuhin has not yet learnt quite how SO works.  I'm trying to helpfully teach him/her how to accept answers.

Comment: No, @Arioch, it doesn't belong as an update to the question. It's not part of the question. It belongs in an answer. Since you didn't put working code to solve the problem in *your* answer, Shuhin put it in an answer of his own. Your answer would have been better if it had demonstrated this, since the only real problem in the original code is the method of determining the length of the buffer.

Comment: @Rob, Ahem, absolutely wrong data type, that could let to AVs or (if attempt at in-place editing) memory corruption - that does not count important problem to you ?
Well, yes. Answer consists of "how" and "what". I prefer "how" part. I have little care for copy-paste monkeys and consider that makign your own implementation teachs you better than copypasting. Yet i agree that code sample has its value too. Also i never worked with Qt, so i cannot neither test the code, nor rely on my experience. And posting as "answer" the hypothetical code that probably works just according to common sense, no

Comment: @Rob In the code in the Q, there is a calling convention mismatch,  a type mismatch, and a missing data length parameter. Arioch got it all, even if the writing could have been clearer.

Comment: Well, i got your point about datatypes. You're most probably right on that point. However "no any data" looks strange to me.

Comment: @David - see Rob's comment to my answer. TByteArray is static one, not dynamic. Calling convention is BAD error, but given no-params function returning int32, it should match by sheer luck. After all Rob seems correct. Original code is poor, yet except of PChar - why didn't it worked ? And what is Length(PAnsiChar) ? Is it basically (Length(AnsiString(PAnsiChar)) or Length(UnicodeString(PAnsiChar)) or maybe Length(array[0..-1]of AnsiChar(PChar^)) ? I did not spot Length instead of StrLen used on pointer... shame, shame...

Comment: @Arioch, `Length(PAnsiChar(x))` has an implicit conversion to AnsiString, so it's equivalent to `StrLen(PAnsiChar(x))`, but without the memory allocation. (`Length` is polymorphic; it won't force a conversion to UnicodeString if the argument type provided converts more naturally to AnsiString.)

Comment: @Rob Length is polymorphic, yet pointer is typeless. I once did PAnsiChar(UnicodeString) or maybe PWideChar(AnsiString) expecting the conversion and was badly bitten. Since then i do not trust automation around PChar types

Comment: Yes, @Arioch, `Pointer` is typeless. That's why you can't call `Length` on one. You can call it on `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar`, though, because those aren't typeless. `PAnsiChar` automatically converts to `AnsiString`; `PWideChar` to `WideString` or `UnicodeString`, depending on availability and context. The reverse conversions never happen implicitly, and the conversions only occur when they're within the same character type. Conversions don't occur "across" character types, so `UnicodeString` never converts to `PAnsiChar`. If you try it, you just get a simple type-cast, not a conversion.

Comment: @Rob, not quite a typecast. Typecast would give me a pointer to StringRec. Instead i get a pointer to string[1]. So some part of "compiler magic" still applies, but only partially...

Comment: @Arioch, that's exactly what a type-cast would give you. The `string` variable holds an address. Type-cast it, and whatever you cast it to still holds that same address, just interpreted as having a different type. If you want a pointer to the first byte allocated by the memory manager, then you need to do some arithmetic, and then it's not a type-cast anymore. If the results before and after an operation aren't binary-identical, then it's not a type-cast; it's a conversion. Compiler magic doesn't factor in to type-casts.

Comment: @Rob, and how then do i get pointer to refcounter and length ? negative offset to pointer(string) ?

Comment: Like I said, @Arioch, do some arithmetic. Type-cast (to `Cardinal` or `Pointer`) to get the underlying address, subtract, and then type-cast the calculated address back to `PStrRec`. If the compiler supported that operation itself, it would be classified as a conversion because the result was not the same as the input.

Answer (score 5):

More straightforward would be using PByte aka ^Byte, not PByteArray.
Though TByteArray is static type, still using arrays adds a risk of random typo like using dynamic arrays.

---

Don't use PChar - it would stop on 1st zero byte. Picture is not a string, it can fairly contains hundreds of zeroes.

You should send length as a separate variable/function.
*int QImage::byteCount () const*
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#byteCount

---

Edit you question please. Are you asking about bits or constbits ? those are different properties!

---

Also:

You should learn about "calling conventions" in you compilers, C++ and Pascal.
You'd better be able to track it on Assembler level.

try marking that procedure with "cdecl" directive in Pascal code, or maybe with "stdcall" directive in both C and Pascal code.

Try h2pas utility from FreePascal for auto-conversion.

---

**Now best of all - drop Qt here**. Making Qt bridges just to read PNG file is very weird and fragile. There are a number of native Delphi libraries with PNG support. Few examples:

- Soft Gems: http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/libs/graphicex-library
- Vampyre: http://imaginglib.sf.net

Comment: Your understanding of PByteArray is wrong. It's not a pointer to a record. It's a pointer to an ordinary array. The *declaration* says the pointed-to array contains MaxInt elements, but that's really just to satisfy range-checking code the compiler might emit, which wouldn't be useful for that kind of array pointer. In practice, the array can have any length. There are no dynamic arrays involved in the question.

Comment: I think my answer is better than of Arioch answer. but I can't check my own answer as finall. So I checked Arioch post as final answer.

Comment: @Rob well, then my memory tricked me. Yes, it is not dynamic array. But then why "no any data returned" ? It should mean that the most 1st byte is already zero ? Even if we skip PNG header - i really know nothing about Qt and topicstarter mixes two different properties - the probability of the 1st pixel to be exactly 0 seems not large.

Comment: @Shuhin_Ashayeri You'd be able to check your own answer in couple of days. AFAIR that should be written on your attempts.
You answer shows what to do, but does neither told what has changed nor why. Imagine person that knows very little in C++ and Pascal. Would he be able to check all you almost totalyl redone code and understand which changes were important and why they were important ? I doubt. Frankly, our answers are complimentary. If you'd highlight and explain changes in your code that would be most useful answer.