# Delphi 6 and signals/slots from a shared library written in QT

Tags: multithreading, qt, delphi, dll, signals

Right now I have an application written in Qt, and a shared library(dll), also written in Qt. They are working in different threads and communicate via signals and slots.

The problem: I need to make the Qt dll work for a Delphi 6 application.

The question: Is it possible to somehow use Qt dll's signals in delphi? If not, how can I make the main program(delphi) and the dll(in a different thread) communicate in some other way, not with signals/slots?

Comment: This may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312968/passing-binary-data-from-qt-c-dll-into-delphi-host-application

Comment: Why are there votes to close? This looks like an interesting and genuine question, and it is currently being discussed in the Embarcadero forums as well.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html). It expains the signal and slot mechanism, a kind of implementation of the Observer pattern which reads the macros used in the Qt source and uses a code generator to create the extra code needed to link up signals to slots and dispatch them. I'm sure it can be emulated, but I'm also sure it would be quite a lot of work. Although, if it is a DLL... I would take a look at the public interface with something like Dependency Walker. I'm sure you can easily write functions that connect slots and signals directly.